# Delete Table in Searchkit

Tags: searchkit

When I create a table in Searchkit and choose the delete button the table isn't being deleted.  Any thoughts on how I can solve this coz I'm getting a list of obsolete ones.  It puts a line through the table, but it isn't actually deleted and still there when I come back to it.
[image: Delete Table Searchkit - doesn't delete]
e.g. in this instance it looks like it's deleted but it isn't and when I come back it's still there.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

After doing the delete, have you hit 'Save'?

Comment: Thank you for responding - yes when I clic save the delete line is removed and the table is still there to see.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org ?  It behaves for me as expected.

Comment: Hi Aidan - no I can't recreate it there.  The demo is working as expected.  The version of civicrm we have is 3.38 and whatever version of searchkit was with core in that version.  Thanks.  I am looking into getting upgraded but might not be as soon as I'd like

Comment: Ok, so looks like it has been fixed since your version.  Upgrading is generally straightforward and quick.

Comment: Thanks I.m waiting on a quote for upgrade